# calling .net web service from android not working

Tags: .net, android, web-services

I am calling a .net web service from my android app with no luck.
Here is my code:

**My packages:**

```
package com.reza;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;
import android.widget.TextView;
```

**The class:**

```
public class callWebservice extends Activity {
     private static final String METHOD_NAME = "HelloWorld";

     private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
     private static final String URL = "http://service.screwedmind.com/LocalBusiness.asmx";
     private static final String SOAP_ACTION = null;
     TextView tv;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.text1);
        call();
    }
    public void call()
    {
            try {

            SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

            SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
            envelope.dotNet=true;
            envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

            HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
            androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

            String result=(String)envelope.getResponse();

            tv.setText(result);
            } 
            catch (Exception e) {
                tv.setText("error occured..");
            }
    }
}
```

when I run this program, I see my error text which is `"error occured..."`
can anybody plz guide me what i am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "error occured.." is your error message, write `tv.setText(e.toString());` and what message do you see there?

Comment: its an ugly message.------SoapFault-faultcode:'soap:Client' faultstring:'System.web.services.protocols.soapexception:Server did not not recognize the value of HTTP Header SOAPAction: HelloWorld. at System.web.services.protocols.soap11ServerProtocolHelper.RouteRequest() at System.web.services.protocols.soapServerProtocol.RouteRequest(SoapServerMessage message) at web.services.protocols.soapServerProtocol.Initialize() at web.services.protocols.soapServerProtocol.SetContext(Type type, HttpContext context,HttpRequest request,HttpResponse response) at ----it goes on..

Comment: The important bit is `Server did not not recognize the value of HTTP Header SOAPAction`, which on checking is because your SOAPAction is null. Try the suggestion by @bigstones to set the SOAP_ACTION.

Comment: Also, the rest of the message is a stack trace showing you where the error occurred and the state of the stack at the time.

Answer (score 0):

you probably only need to set `SOAP_ACTION = NAMESPACE + METHOD_NAME`

Answer (score 0):

You should change SOAP_ACTION = NAMESPACE + METHOD_NAME

Comment: This solution has been posted